# Verify mocked objects before the test ends

Tags: mocking, phpunit

We are migrating from PHPUnit 5 to PHPUnit 8.

And we have discovered that `verifyMockObjects()` is now a private method.

We use it a lot in our tests like this:

- set up some context for the test
- mock some objects
- run some user-land code
- assert it works well with `verifyMockObjects()`
- mock some more objects
- run some user-land code
- assert it works well with verifyMockObjects()
- ...

An example would be an iterator:
- we check it once set up
- we check it after the first loop
- we check it after the second loop
- ...

Using `verifyMockObjects()` helps us to set up some milestones in the test.
Is there a workaround or a best practice we should be aware of since `verifyMockObjects()` is now private?

Thanks!

Related to https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/3734